# C Program - Prime numbers

Tags: c

It is to determine whether a number is prime or not.
Executed using Codeblocks 13.12.
Compiler GNU GCC 4.7.0

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int input,check,count;

    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("&d",&check);

    count=0;        
    for(check=1;check<=1;check++)
    {
        if((input%check)==0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count==2)
    {
        printf("The number %d is prime",check);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The number %d is not prime",check);
    }
}
```

Please note that there is no error or warning.
But the compiler assumes a number "2" even after giving someother input and it says 2 is not prime!!

Comment: First thing wrong: your title.

Comment: Wintermute is right, also you should add `int` before `main()` and in your `for` loop, you reset `check`'s value to 1. There's a few things to fix.

Comment: Among other things the for loop is such that check starts at 1 and can be less than or equal to 1, and is incremented, therefore it only runs once -- it doesn't appear to be modified in the loop at all....furthermore, it is at a minimum confusing to use "check" for both the scanf variable and the for loop variable {not sure how C resolves this, frankly, in some languages, it would just overwrite it, but perhaps there are separate instances for each scope).

Comment: I get 3 warnings with gcc -- two for the malformed `main`, and `warning: too many arguments for format` for the mis-used `scanf` line.

Comment: Return `int` from `main()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I assume it always comes down to someone doing the code for the asker anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() // note "int" before "main()"
{
    int input, check, count;
    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &input); //I believe this is what you meant instead of storing the inputted value in "check"

    count = 0;
    check = 2; //Check should equal "2" because anything divided by one will have no remainder


    while((count != 1) && (check <= 50)) //If you want to stop trying to divide when the number you're dividing by is above 50, change this line. I stopped at 50 just as a random number, but I'm sure there's a more logical one to use. ------ "while(count != 1)" stops the loop when the number is successfully divided.

    {
        if (check == input) break; // stop checking when the number we're trying to divide is equal to the number to divide by.

        if((input%check) == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }

        check++; //increment the number we're checking by
    }

    if(count == 1)
    {
        printf("The number %d is not prime\n", input); // output the number the user tried to input
    }

    else
    {
        printf("The number %d is prime\n", input);
    }

    getch();
    return 1;
}
```

I beg of you to read the comments and understand them instead of just copying the code, as I've seen done so many times.

Edit: My mistake for originally including a c++ function. It's in C now.

Comment: The OP is **not** tagged with [tag:c++] tag.

Comment: Sorry about that. Simple fix.

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("&d",&check);
```

should be

```
//     v-- percent, not ampersand
scanf("%d",&check);
```

Or (probably)

```
scanf("%d", &input);
```

...since it would make a lot more sense to read into the `input` variable. Later in the program, then,

```
printf("The number %d is prime", check);
```

should be

```
printf("The number %d is prime\n", input);
```

because you're checking `input`, not `check`. The same two lines below that. Finally, the loop condition in

```
for(check=1;check<=1;check++)
```

makes no sense. The loop would run exactly once, and you don't want to test if input is divisible by 1. It would make sense with

```
                 // v-- check factors until input
for(check=1;check<=input;check++)
```

This is not the most efficient check here, but it's something to get you started.

Side note: the prototype

```
main()
```

is compliant only with C89. From C99 onwards, the old K&R method of function declaration is no longer included, and the proper equivalent prototype for main is

```
int main(void)
```

So while you're fixing things, you should put that there.

Comment: Yeees, there's a few more things. Took me a moment to see them all.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues are:

1. Variable `input` is not defined which contains garbage value.
2. `for(check=1;check<=1;check++)` This seems incorrect, loops only once for all cases.
3. Read values using scanf by passing format specifier as `%d` instead of `&d`.